# Laravel 5.6: storing image into public folder via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm making an admin panel for a personal project as a means to studying laravel framework, so far I'm loving it!

I came up with a issue where I don't know how to store the uploaded image into my app (I'd like to use public folder instead of other storage despite being less secure), I have my folder called uploads inside public.

This is my AJAX POST call:

```js
$('.form_store_button').click(function(){
  
  var linked_entry = $(this).attr("data-link");
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  
  
  
  
  $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content') }
        });
  

  switch(linked_entry) {
            
   case "sliders":
   
       console.log('new slider button clicked');
    
    var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('title', form.closest($("input[name='title']").val()));
                formData.append('body', form.closest($("textarea[name='body']").val()));
                formData.append('image', form.closest($("input[name='image']").prop('files')[0]));
    formData.append('isVisible', form.closest($("input[name='isVisible']").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0));

    
                $.ajax({

                async: true,
                url: '/sliders',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                dataType: 'JSON',
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
            
                success: function (data) { 
           $('.form_valid_container').html('<span class="form_valid_text">✓ '+ data.success +'</span>');
        form.trigger("reset");
           console.log(data.success, data.errors);
                },
   
       error: function (data){
                    var errors = data.responseJSON;
                    console.log(errors);
    
        $.each(errors , function(){
                        $('.form_error_container').html('<span class="form_error_text">✘ '+ errors.message +'</span>')
                    }); 
                }
    
    
    });

      break;
     
     

            default:
                        
        }
    
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my controller where I try to store the image (but ultimately fail).

```js
public function store(StoreSlider $request)
    {
  
  
        $slider = new Slider();
        $slider->title = $request->title;
        $slider->body = $request->body;
  $slider->image = $request->file('image');
  $slider->isVisible = $request->isVisible;
        $slider->save();
  
        return response()->json($slider);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to follow,

1. You have to store the image in public directory
2. Store the public path in database

To store a image, you need to have the following data,

1. filename and extension of uploaded image
2. public path

```
public function store(StoreSlider $request)
    {
        $uploadFile = $request->file('image');

        //generate random filename and append original extension (eg: asddasada.jpg, asddasada.png)
        $filename = str_random(6).'.'.$uploadFile->extension();

        // storing path (Change it to your desired path in public folder)
        $path = 'img/uploads';

        // Move file to public filder
        $uploadFile->storeAs('../../public/'.$path, $filename);

        $slider = new Slider();
        $slider->title = $request->title;
        $slider->body = $request->body;
        $slider->image = $path.'/'.$filename; // So that you can access image by url($slider->image);
        $slider->isVisible = $request->isVisible;
        $slider->save();

        return response()->json($slider);
    }
```

Comment: Im getting the following error: message: "Impossible to create the root directory \"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Restaurante1\\storage\\app\\C:/xampp/htdocs/Restaurante1/public/img/uploads\".", exception: "League\\Flysystem\\Exception", file: "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Restaurante1\\vendor\\league\\flysystem\\src\\Adapter\\Local.php"

Comment: this is weird since I created an uploads folder inside img folder in public directory

Comment: change the $path variable to '../../public/img/uploads/'

Comment: changing the `$path` variable to `../../public/img/uploads/`, stores the same ini database. Which causes invalid url on retrieve(`url($slider->image`)). So, see the updated answer